# Nodejs asynchronous task and anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following example is the current code :

```
new SomeStrategy(function(one, two, done) { 
    // do some stuff
    return done(pram);
})
```

I  want to do some asynchronous tasks inside that anonymous function like initiating request and use the result as a parameter in done function and finally return

> return done(parameter);

How could it be done ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a value from an asynchronous function.

By the time it has finished executing, the function that called it will have finished so there won't be anywhere to return the value to.

You have to do whatever work you want to do with the results of the asynchronous function inside the callback function you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `done` from the inner anonymous function, like this

```
new SomeStrategy(function(one, two, done) { 
    callAsyncFunction(param1, function(param1) {
        done(pram);
    });
})
```

Comment: @enGMzizo We are already in an asynchronous function. Where will that value be returned?

Comment: the anonymous function in SomeStrategy should return what comes from **done(pram)**